# Angular ngOnchanges calls method, but method does not call service or output results

Tags: angular, ngoninit, ngonchanges

I am confused by what is happening in a section of my app.  I have a component that uses ngOnChanges.  ngOnchanges fires right before ngOnInit when the component loads.  Both ngOnChanges and ngOnInit call a certain method (fetchResults) that calls an api service to get some data using an observable return.  I have a `tap` on my call to the service to console log the returned data and also a breakpoint in vs for the api method that gets called.

When the initial call to `fetchResults` is made from the `ngOnChanges` hook, the service does not return any data and the api breakpoint is not hit.  However, when the `ngOnInit` hook is triggered and the `fetchResults` is called a second time, the api breakpoint is hit and the console log displays the returned data.

Why is this happening?  I am expecting any call to `fetchResults` to hit the api and return data.  I have validated that the required param is being passed.  The call from `ngOnChanges` and the the call from `ngOnInit` are identical.

Sample code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('fetchResults called from ngOnInit')
    this.fetchResults(this.itemId);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('ngOnChanges called with changes value: ', changes)
    this.fetchResults(changes['propName'].currentValue)
  }

fetchResults(itemId){
    console.log('fetchResults function called with competitionId: ', itemId)
    
    this.resultList$ = this.dataservice.getResults(itemId)
      .pipe( 
        map( result => {
          return result.map(
            item => {
              return item;
            }
          )
        }),
        tap(val => console.log(' fetchResults function - the value of returned result object: ', val))
      )
  }
```

Result Component Html with async binding:

```
... this.resultList$ | async" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that second time *fetchResults* method is called (when ngOnChanges executes it), your observable attribute **resultList$** is "re-assigned" to a new observable object.

---

Anyway, if you want to test if you really are getting data or not both times, change your *fetchResults* method to get a different subscription any time (just for testing):

```
fetchResults(itemId){
    console.log('fetchResults function called with competitionId: ', itemId)
    
    this.dataservice.getResults(itemId)
      .pipe( 
        map( result => {
          return result.map(
            item => {
              return item;
            }
          )
        })
      ).subscribe(
         val => console.log(' fetchResults function - the value of returned result object: ', val)
      )}
```

---

Finally, if you want to "fix" it, you could do something like this:

```
// In your declaration of Class attributes:
get resultList$(itemId){

   return this.dataservice.getResults(itemId)
      .pipe( 
        map( result => {
          return result.map(
            item => {
              return item;
            }
          )
        }),
        tap(val => console.log(' fetchResults function - the value of returned result object: ', val))
   );

}

Class...

Cosntructor....

ngOnInit() {
    console.log('fetchResults called from ngOnInit')
    this.resultList$ = this.itemId;
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('ngOnChanges called with changes value: ', changes)
    this.resultList$ = changes['propName'].currentValue);
}
```

Comment: I made an edit to specify the async binding.  I also tried your suggestion to test and indeed the api is now being called twice as I would expect.  Why is that not happening when I use the async binding?

Comment: (ok, as I thought...) You can see the way at the beggining of my answer: When NgOnIt execute the fetchResults method (I mean, the second time that method is executed), resultList$ is "re-assigned" to a new observable object, so the first assignation is lost... So you only can get the values of the second time.

Comment: I've just edited my answer with a possible solution that fits your requeriments. Give it a try and good luck!

Comment: Sorry but I think you have it backwards.  The first call is from `ngOnChanges`.  The second call is from `ngOnInit`.  The first call does not hit the api.  The second call does.  I want to know why the first call does not trigger the api when I am binding to the tamplate using async without using a `subscribe`.